# Can't get a good connection remotle with roscore

Tags: linux

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

For some kind of reason I'm unable to get a good connection remotely with roscore. I have on my Jetson Nano roscore running and setup the ./bashrc file with ip address

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.178.63:11311
export ROS_IP=192.168.178.63
```

When I do a ifconfig on Ubuntu (running on VMware)
I get as IP addres 192.168.204.128

So on my Ubuntu VM is set in the ./bashrc file

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://192.168.178.63:11311
export ROS_IP=192.168.204.128
```

Now when I run a publisher on my Jetson Nano (e.g. Hello World) and can subscribe to the topic on the destkop Ubuntu machine and see the data comming in.
But when I run a publisher on my desktop (e.g. Hello World) the Jetson doesn't see the data comming in. Although when I do a rostopic list it shows the topic.

Does anybody knows how to fix this? I must do something wrong. I think t is the network settings but I cant change the IP addres of the VM, I tried to change it but it did give me the good results I was even unable to connect to roscore.

Some help would be appreciated

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/418141/can%27t-get-a-good-connection-remotle-with-roscore/) by [ElectricRay](https://answers.ros.org/users/143055/electricray/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2023-08-04

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2023-08-05**:
I will assume when you say "the Jetson doesn't see the data" you mean you have a subscriber running on the Jetson and the subscriber callback doesn't get entered.  I have to ask, does it work if you the run both publisher and subscriber on the desktop?  You're running same version of ROS on both machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have figured out what went wrong. It were a couple of things all related to eachother. So as you can see in my question the IP address of the desktop and Jetson Nano were not in the same range. This creates issues, in order to fix this when using a Virtual Machine one needs to bridge the network card. As I was using WiFi on my destkop and have the free version of VMware I could not bridge the WiFi card.
So what I did is connect my desktop with a LAN cable to my router and that bridge the network card.

By doing this I am able to send between publishers and subscribers n both direction data messages.

So problem solved

---

Originally posted by [ElectricRay](https://answers.ros.org/users/143055/electricray/) with karma: 11 on 2023-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-08-06**:
Please click on the checkmark in the gray circle to indicate you (the question author) accept this answer. The icon will turn green.

**Comment by [ElectricRay](https://answers.ros.org/users/143055/electricray/) on 2023-08-06**:
I tried to do so but I dont have enough points to do this

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2023-08-06**:
oh yeah, I forgot about that.

**Comment by [ElectricRay](https://answers.ros.org/users/143055/electricray/) on 2023-08-06**:
np, I don't know how I receive points I have two questions answered by myself because I fogured it out eventually and thought would be good to close them.

**Comment by [billy](https://answers.ros.org/users/26871/billy/) on 2023-08-08**:
I +1'd this post so maybe now you have the points needed.

**Comment by [ElectricRay](https://answers.ros.org/users/143055/electricray/) on 2023-08-08**:
Thanks! as you can see now I have the rights :)